# Cannot pass Ruins Top level on Lugaru HD

Tags: lugaru-hd

I'm playing Lugaru HD on Fedora 33 (Linux).

There is a really hard level on Temple map. I can't found any way to go to rabbits on top. To understand, please watch my video.

If you look the map in game, you can see enemies in top.

Comment: idk this game but if the levels are numbered or titled it would help to include that

Comment: Level title is **Ruins Top**. This level is in **Temple** map, there isn't any number.

Comment: It's *really* hard to see the map, let alone the enemies. Can you describe what you see on the map, or upload a high resolution screenshot of the map in front of an even (dark) colour?

Answer (score 0):

Jumping from a crouching position should get you there.

From the Lugaru wiki ([Jumping](http://wiki.wolfire.com/index.php/Lugaru_Character_Movement#Jumping)):

> Pressing the jump key (default is the Space bar) causes Turner to leap straight into the air. The longer the key is held, the higher the jump. The highest jumps are achieved by starting from a crouching position. This will often allow you to reach the edge of a block otherwise out of reach.